# How to make a program loop until the user inputs the correct username and password

Tags: python

I have made a program that asks for a username and password until entered correctly.

**Code:**

```
def main():
    endProgram ="no"
    while endProgram =="no":
        print("Welcome to the program :D")
        print("-------------------------")

        username =778922
        password =2713
        login = ""
        while login ==username:
            username = int(input("Username: "))
            password = int(input("Passowrd: "))


        endProgram = raw_input("Do you wish to end the program")

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while` loop will never be anything different because you set `endProgram` to `'no'` before anything else.

Here's code that will prompt the user to enter their login info (username) and repeat if the username is not found:

```
def main():
    endProgram = input('do you wish to end the program?')
    while endProgram == 'no':
        print('Welcome')
        username = 778922
        password = 2713
        login = input('What\'s your login info?')
        if login==username:
            username = int(input("Username: "))
            password = int(input("Password: "))

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

change the condition of your while loop to this :

```
while username != input_name or password != input_password:
    #continue to take inputs or end program
```

This way your inner while loop will continue to loop until the correct username is entered. To exit this loop if the user can't enter a correct username or password you can do the following

```
endProgram = raw_input("Do you wish to end the program")
if endProgram == "yes":
    break
```

Comment: He is on Python3 I recommend you change `raw_input` to `input`